# negative number in my datagridview

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I'm having problem in my datagridview.

I'm using vb 2008 and an access database. When I create a new record for my item the `No` column (primary key and autonumber in access) always shows a negative number.

How can I make that a positive number and it should follow the numbering in the datagridview. Here's a screen shot of that:

[image]

Comment: What is your DataGridView bound to, a DataTable?

Comment: yes, i just drag the it from the data sources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "No" column will start out with an AutoIncrementSeed of -1 and an AutoIncrementStep of -1.  The DataSet isn't smart enough to start with the Max value of the "No" column, so you need to programatically set it.

```
Me.MyDataSet.MyDataTable.Columns("No").AutoIncrementSeed = _
Me.MyDataSet.MyDataTable.Max(Function(Row) Row.No) + 1

Me.MyDataSet.MyDataTable.Columns("No").AutoIncrementStep = 1
```

The first line above finds the maximum value of the No column and sets the AutoIncrementSeed to 1 above the maximum value.  The second line just sets the IncrementStep to 1.

Keep in mind that the No column in the DataGridView may not correspond to the actual value that the database creates.  When your data is committed, the database will create a new AutoNumber value, ignoring any other values you may pass in.  There are some pitfalls to doing this if your users expect the No value to stay the same after committing the new entry.

Answer (score 1):

Just open the dataset designer and look for the increment parameter (-1) for the applicable datagriview of the table concerned and  change it to (+1). Then, rebuild or recompile your application and the problem will done with.

Answer (score 0):

```
if its showing in negative 

check the logic why its converted to negative

changing - to + dosent matters, but logic ??
```

> **CONVERT AS put condition as column1>=0**